# How to get album art using Spotify web api with Gson

Tags: android, gson, spotify

I'm using the [spotify web api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) to get a json object containing album information.

Here is the model url

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album:arrival%20artist:abba&type=album
```

So let's say I'm looking for the album "Nevermind" by "Nirvana" and I have this url

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album:nevermind%20artist:nirvana&type=album

So I've made a "model object" for Gson here

```
public class SpotifyAlbumInfo {

    public CollectionInfo collectionInfo;

    public class CollectionInfo {

        String href;
        List<Album> albums;     
        Integer limit;
        String next;      
        Integer offset;
        String previous;  
        Integer total6;

        public class Album{
            String album_type;
            String[] available_markets;
            Urls external_urls;
            String href;
            String id;
            List<Image> images;
            String name;
            String type;
            String uri;

            public class Urls{
                String source;
            }

            public class Image {
                Integer height;
                String url;
                Integer width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here I'm trying to get the first image url

```
for(int i=0;i<response.collectionInfo.albums.images.size();i++){       
    if(response.collectionInfo.albums.image.get(i).contains("nevermind")){
        imageUrl = response.collectionInfo.albums.images.get(i).url;
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this statement is fine

```
response.collectionInfo.albums.size();
```

But I can't use

```
response.collectionInfo.albums.images.size();
```

Because I get the error `symbol does not exist`.

I get the same error for these statements.

```
response.collectionInfo.albums.images.size(); 
response.collectionInfo.albums.album_type.size();
response.collectionInfo.albums.href.size();
// etc
```

How do I go "a layer deeper" into my "model object" and get the image url I want?

Comment: Why are you using the web api instead of the Android SDK?

Comment: I didn't know I could use the SDK to do this.

Comment: Neither do I, but it's worth a look rather than dealing with manually parsing JSON responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a specific album from the list

```
collectionInfo.albums
```

There is no `images` field for a `List` interface, which some error code is probably trying to tell you.

You can drill down like so

```
Album album0 = collectionInfo.albums.get(0);
album0.images.size()
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So basically `response.collectionInfo.albums.get(0).images.size();`

Comment: Yeah, just keep track of which objects you are dealing with after each dot, and you'll be good. Using autocomplete really helps with that, too